# Java Spring-Hibernate synchronize issue on database update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, synchronization

I am trying to create a user (in a synchronized block) on calling a function. When there are multiple parallel calls, it is creating multiple users with same emailId, even though the user is already created in synchronized block.

Note that, the emailId field in my database is not unique and I cannot change it to be unique.

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    public void myFunction(String emailId){
      //do something
      synchronized(this) 
      {
        boolean userExists = checkDuplicateEmail(emailId);  //checkDuplicateEmail is a hibernate query.
        if(!userExists){
            createUser();
        }
      }
    }
}

public class UserDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UserDAO {
    public boolean checkDuplicateEmail(String email) throws TechnicalException {
        try {
            boolean isExist = false;

            Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.flush();

            DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(user.class);
            criteria.add(Property.forName("emailId").eq(email));
            criteria.setProjection(Projections.count("emailId"));
            List users = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
            if (users != null && users.size() > 0) {
                if (((Integer) users.get(0)) > 0l) {
                    isExist = true;
                }
            }
            return isExist;
        } catch (DataAccessException dataAccessException) {
            throw dataAccessException;
        }
    }
}
```

The block is executing in a synchronized manner. But hibernate is not returning the right data.

Comment: This is pretty common mistake doing synchronization within a trasaction. I am pretty sure I will be able to to search duplicate question...

Comment: @pavel: the question you provided is not the same, i already have a synchronized block and the block IS synchronized. But the hibernate is not seeing the newly created user.

Comment: You are performing synchronization under an active transaction. When the synchronization block ends, the transaction is not yet committed (thus other threads entering synchronized block are *"not seeing newly created user"*). The underlying issue is exactly the same as in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

you said you are getting incorrect result from your criteria :
try setting uniqueResult on your email and if null is returned by the criteria, that means the User with that email is not present in the database:

```
User user =(User)session.createCriteria(User.class)
        .add( Restrictions.eq("emailId",email)
        .setMaxResults(1)
        .uniqueResult();

  if(user!=null){
    isExist=true;
}
 else{
        isExist=false;
    }
```

Comment: When I say "not returning the right data." it means after creating the user, when I query to check if user exists it returns false but it should return true.